# Manually recover the original function from numpy rfft

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have performed a `numpy.fft.rfft` on a function to obtain the Fourier coefficients.  Since [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html#numpy.fft.rfft) do not seem to contain the exact formula used, I have been assuming a formula found in a textbook of mine:

`S(x) = a_0/2 + SUM(real(a_n) * cos(nx) + imag(a_n) * sin(nx))`

where `imag(a_n)` is the imaginary part of the `n_th` element of the Fourier coefficients.

To translate this into python-speak, I have implemented the following:

```
def fourier(freqs, X):
    # input the fourier frequencies from np.fft.rfft, and arbitrary X
    const_term = np.repeat(np.real(freqs[0])/2, X.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)
    # this is the "n" part of the inside of the trig terms
    trig_terms = np.tile(np.arange(1,len(freqs)), (X.shape[0],1))
    sin_terms = np.imag(freqs[1:])*np.sin(np.einsum('i,ij->ij', X, trig_terms))
    cos_terms = np.real(freqs[1:])*np.cos(np.einsum('i,ij->ij', X, trig_terms))
    return np.concatenate((const_term, sin_terms, cos_terms), axis=1)
```

This should give me an `[X.shape[0], 2*freqs.shape[0] - 1]` array, containing at entry `i,j` the `i_th` element of `X` evaluated at the `j_th` term of the Fourier decomposition (where the `j_th` term is a `sin` term for odd `j`).

By summing this array over the axis of Fourier terms, I should obtain the function evaluated at the `i_th` term in `X`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-1,1,50)
y = X*(X-0.8)*(X+1)

reconstructed_y = np.sum(
    fourier(
        np.fft.rfft(y), 
        X
    ),
    axis = 1
)

plt.plot(X,y)
plt.plot(X, reconstructed_y, c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In any case, the red line should be basically on top of the blue line.  Something has gone wrong either in my assumptions about what `numpy.fft.rfft` returns, or in my specific implementation, but I am having a hard time tracking down the bug.  Can anyone shed some light on what I've done wrong here?

Comment: To be clear: I DO NOT WANT to simply perform an `numpy.fft.irfft`.  I have simplified my "goals" to create a minimal reproducible problem.  I want to extract the individual basis functions and do further processing on them, but it is clear that I am not interpreting the basis functions correctly, as illustrated by this simplified example.

Comment: `real(a_n) * cos(nx) + imag(a_n) * sin(nx)` is not how complex multiplication works. You want to do `a_n * (cos(nx)+i*sin(nx))`. NumPy should be able to do this complex multiplication correctly for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ahhhhh.... what a rookie mistake.

Comment: @CrisLuengo In retrospect, it shouldn't matter, since the imaginary terms should all fall out, since the original signal was real...

Comment: The output of `rfft` does not give you the negative frequency terms since they are symmetric with the positive frequency terms.  For the reconstruction, you will need to mirror the signal about zero.  For what you are trying to do, I would suggest using `fft` instead of `rfft` so the transform will give you those terms directly (at the cost of some speed).

Comment: @ChrisMueller that solved the problem.